# How to unit test CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, routedevent

I am trying to write a unit test for the following code:

```
public static void AppExitCmdCanExecute(object sender,
                                        CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

The problem with this code is that I am not able to create a mock instance (sealed class ) or instance (internal constructor) of CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs type.

I tried the following, but both the following code throw run-time exception.

```
[Test()]
public void AppExitCmdCanExecuteTest()
{
    object sender = null;
    //Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.
    var mockArgs = new Moq.Mock<CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs>();
    AppCommands.AppExitCmdCanExecute(sender, mockArgs.Object);
    Assert.IsTrue(mockArgs.CanExecute);
}

[Test()]
public void AppExitCmdCanExecuteTest()
{
    object sender = null;                
    //Constructor on type 'System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs'
    // not found.
    var mockArgs = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs),
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                            BindingFlags.Instance,
                                            new object[2] {fakeCommand, 
                                                           fakeParameter});
    AppCommands.AppExitCmdCanExecute(sender, mockArgs);
    Assert.IsTrue(mockArgs.CanExecute);
}
```

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used [the wrong overload of `CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx). Use this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs),
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
                         new object[2] {fakeCommand, fakeParameter}, null);
```

You need to make sure that `fakeCommand` is not `null`, as the constructor has a guard clause for that parameter.

Comment: Sure enough, that is indeed the problem. This works! I just tried it.

Comment: Sure it works ;-) BTW: The exception message tells you, that the problem is that your command parameter is null: `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: command`